# Why avoid writing one-sentence paragraphs?

Tags: paragraphs

I am told to avoid writing one-sentence paragraphs. What are some good reasons for following this rule?

Comment: This is off-topic on ELU. Writing advice is available on other websites, eg Writers.SE.

Comment: To avoid the appearance of being a New York Times reporter or editor.

Comment: I don't know... how long is your sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is a request for opinions about guidance given to writers, and not about English language and usage as defined in the help center.

Comment: Count the sentences in Dicken's famous paragraph *"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, ..."*

Comment: @PeterShor: Or try Proust. ^_^

Comment: @PeterShor But rules are different for literary prose than for other types of writing (scientific, formal etc)

Comment: @Catija: Millikan's famous "oil-drop experiment" paper starts with the paragraph: *The experiments herewith reported were undertaken with the view of introducing certain improvements into the oil-drop method of determining e and N and thus obtaining a higher accuracy than had before been possible in the evaluation of these most fundamental constants.* The third paragraph (which I will not quote here) is also a single sentence. And there are at least two more single-sentence paragraphs later in the paper.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not arguing it's a rule... to be honest.  I think my first comment shows that it really depends on the sentence... I'd honestly still argue that that example is more of a preamble on method to the paper than part of the paper itself.

Comment: To answer the question, if you find yourself writing a single-sentence paragraph, ask yourself *"do I actually need this paragraph?"* *"would this be clearer if I incorporated this sentence into the previous or the following paragraph?"*. If the answers are *"yes"* and *"no"*, leave it as is.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Could you help me migrate this to Writers? Thanks.

Comment: The main point is that if you have a lot of one-sentence paragraphs you likely either 1) are writing sentences that are too long, or 2) are not properly using paragraphs to encompass and delineate a *complete* thought or concept.  But it's a judgment call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with writing a single sentence paragraph, so long as that sentence communicates the desired message.

The [UNC Writing Center](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/paragraphs/) says:

> Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph. A paragraph is defined as “a group of sentences or a single sentence that forms a unit” (Lunsford and Connors 116). Length and appearance do not determine whether a section in a paper is a paragraph. For instance, in some styles of writing, particularly journalistic styles, a paragraph can be just one sentence long. Ultimately, a paragraph is a sentence or group of sentences that support one main idea.

Comment: Superb answer. But not the correct place for it. Still, I'm filing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since each paragraph supposedly has a purpose for being, at least one sentence would be needed to state that point. Additional statements would usually be required to elucidate, expand upon, or support that idea. A one sentence paragraph would probably either be excessive in length or insufficiently expressive of the idea.

Comment: Look at the one-sentence first paragraph of Millikan's oil-drop experiment paper (given in the comments above) and tell me why it is excessive in length or insufficiently expressive of the idea.

Comment: I said specifically "Additional statements would usually be required... ." That certainly allows for exceptions; some of which are notable because they are just that: exceptions.

Comment: The person asked what reasons would support the idea of having more than one sentence in a paragraph.